# Where to declare and initialize NSUserDefaults and the like?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing my first Cocoa app.

For now, every time I need the `NSUserDefaults`, I'm initialising an object of the class and use it in the local scope.

This is a bit tedious. so I'm wondering where I should put the `NSUserDefaults` declaration and initialisation so that it might be available for all my `Application Delegate` methods?

Comment: Don't alloc-init `NSUserDefaults` at all. Use the shared instance (`[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`).

Comment: Why dont you use sharedUserDefaults ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply be using this singleton when trying to use user defaults

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with calling the defaults wherever you need it. It's a singleton anyway.

If you put it into your app delegate you'll just be calling into that the same way to get the NSUserDefaults.

If you want to initialise the defaults for your app - the place to do that is in the `+initialize` method of your app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm initialising an object of the class and use it in the local scope.`

It is not required at all. If you want to save something in UserDefaults, cocoa provides you a shared instance / Singleton of that.

Whenever you need to update your saved value, you call `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and use it, and only one instance will be saved for you.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourObject forKey:@"yourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do user defaults is to create your own `PFXDefaults` class (replace `PFX` with your favorite prefix) which has methods for accessing and mutating the values that you care about.  This allows you to write

```
[[PFXDefaults sharedDefaults] setUserName:@"Nate"];
```

rather than

```
[[NSUserDefaults] setObject:@"Nate" forKey:@"userName"];
```

It is often convenient to make this class a prefix, or, barring that, a visible (declared in the `.h` file) property on your app delegate.

The `PFXDefaults` interface would look something like

```
@interface PFXDefaults : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *userName;

@end
```

and the implementation would look something like

```
static NSString * const PFXDefaultUserNameKey = @"PFXDefaultUserNameKey";

@implementation PFXDefaults

- (void)setUserAge:(NSString *)userName
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userName forKey:PFXDefaultUserNameKey];
}

- (NSInteger)userAge
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:PFXDefaultUserNameKey];
}

@end
```

Comment: Personally I would place this functionality in a class extension.

Comment: Using a category on NSUserDefaults is certainly another option--and one which avoids the spectre of introducing a new singleton.